# How to add cases in bullet points in a list?

Tags: itemize, enumitem, typography

I wish to have something like the following

- Case 1: bla bla bla

  (i)  bla bla bla

  (ii) bla bla bla
- Case 2: bla bla bla

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you mean by " add section` ...

MWE, which reproduce showed desired result can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
\item   Case 1: bla bla bla
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item   bla bla bla
\item   bla bla bla
    \end{enumerate}
\item   Case 2: bla bla bla
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
\item   Case 1: bla bla bla
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),align=left]
\item   bla bla bla
\item   bla bla bla
    \end{enumerate}
\item   Case 2: bla bla bla
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A quick question following your solution; when I input an equation in case 2 it destroys the documents "aligness", how shall I fix this?

Comment: Actually, never mind, I was being stupid again ha!

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by saying that I did not really understand what you'd want to achieve, but I tried something. Since it's such a weird way to display things, the results are not so good looking.

I suggest using the `enumitem` package, this way you can customize your lists.

You could momentarily change the `\item` label by adding a square bracket: `\item[<new-label>]`, but I am using the much better alternative (since we want to modify all the labels) `[label=<label>]` placed right at the start of the `enumerate` environment.

A possibility would be to use a table, but I could not think of a way to do so.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

% This is the first option
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Case \arabic*]
    \item bla bla bla
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
        \item bla bla bla
        \item bla bla bla
    \end{enumerate}
    \item bla bla bla
\end{enumerate}


% second alternative
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbullet~\bfseries Case \arabic*]
    \item bla bla bla
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*), align=left]
        \item bla bla bla
        \item bla bla bla
    \end{enumerate}
    \item bla bla bla
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The answer by Zarko is what I wanted. I wanted the two cases to be clear. However, I appreciate your answer :)

Comment: Thank you, I'm happy that your question has been answered!